# Word Guessing Game in Python?

Tags: python

I'm in a basic programming class and I'm a bit stuck working on this game. The idea was to create a simple word-guessing game, where the computer would choose a random word and you would attempt to guess first some letter in the word, then the word itself after 5 tries. I've gone through multiple times and I still get an error of "Invalid Syntax" when I attempt to run the module. 
I'm a bit dyslexic when it comes to programming languages, so maybe there's something I'm overlooking?
I would appreciate it if someone out there could offer a bit of help!

```
#Word Guessing Game
#Computer picks a random word
#Player tries to guess it
#computer only responds with yes or no

import random

tries = 0

print "Welcome to the word game!"
print "\nI'm going to think of a word and you have to guess it!"
print "\nGuess which letters are in the word, then you have to guess the whole thing!"
print "\nGood luck!"

WORDS = ("follow", "waking", "insane", "chilly", "massive", 
         "ancient", "zebra", "logical", "never", "nice")

word = random.choice(WORDS)

correct = word
length = len(word)
length = str(length)

guess = raw_input("The word is " + length + " letters long. Guess a letter!: ")

while tries < 5:
    for guess in word:
        if guess not in word:
            print "Sorry, try again."
        else:
            print "Good job! Guess another!"

    tries = tries + 1 #*

    if tries = 5:
        final = raw_input ("Try to guess the word!: ")

        if final = correct:
            print "Amazing! My word was ", word, "!"

        else:
            print "Sorry. My word was ", word, ". Better luck next time!"

raw_input("\n\nPress enter to exit")
```

It should also be noted that the problems occurred after the end of the "while tries" block, when I attempted to specify the limits of the "tries" variable. I've worked with it before in a random number game, but for some reason it didn't work properly here. I would greatly appreciate some help!
It should also be noted that I run on a rather outdated version of Python, some variation of 2.0, I believe.

Comment: what do you expect `for guess in word:` to do?

Comment: @Hodge-PodgeCrush, I cleaned up the whitespace in the OP.  Make sure that the line with the `#*` has the same indentation in the question as it does in your code.  Everything else seemed fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
    tries = tries + 1

    if tries == 5:
        final = raw_input ("Try to guess the word!: ")

        if final == correct:
```

You need `==` for comparison not `=`, `=` is for assignment.

You can also replace `tries = tries + 1` with  `tries += 1`

You also want to move `raw_input` inside the loop and just ask the user to guess the word outside the while when the guesses are all used up:

```
while tries < 5:
    guess = raw_input("The word is " + length + " letters long. Guess a letter!: ")
    if guess not in word: # use  `in` to check if the guess/letter is in the word
        print "Sorry, try again."
    else:
        print "Good job! Guess another!"

    tries += 1

# guesses are all used up when we get here
final = raw_input ("Try to guess the word!: ")

if final == correct:
    print "Amazing! My word was ", word, "!"

else:
    print "Sorry. My word was ", word, ". Better luck next time!"
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one.

```
import random 

index = -1
infi = ("python","jumble","hide","mama")

word = random.choice(infi)
word_len = len(word)
guess = ""
attempt = 0
enter = ""
print(word)
temp = "_" * word_len

print("\t\t The word chosen by computer contain", word_len,"letters.")
print("\t  Tap any letter to check if this letter is in computer word.\n")
print("\t You got 5 attempts to check if tapped letter is in computer word.\n")
print("\t\t\t\t GOOD LUCK!!!\n\n\n\n")

for i in range(0, 5):
    attempt +=1
    guess = input("Attempt no. "+str(attempt)+":")
    if guess in word and guess != enter:
        for i in range(0, word_len):
            if guess == word[i]:
                temp = temp[:i] + guess +temp[i+1:]
        print("yes\n" + temp)  
    if guess not in word:
        print("no")
    if "_" not in temp:
        print("\t\t*********** Congratulation!! You guess the word *************")
        break
    elif attempt == 5:
        guess = input("And the word is:")
        if guess == word:

            print("\t\t*********** Congratulation!! You guess the word *************")
        else:
            print("\t\t*********** WRONG!! Shame on you *************")
```